# How can I tell what is triggering Bluetooth in use icon on my menubar

Tags: macos, bluetooth, icon, menu-bar

I have enabled the Bluetooth menu bar item in System Preferences.  Now, whenever a device is trying to talk to my Mac (or vice versa, I suppose) I will see the Bluetooth icon with 3-dots through it.

[image]

Question:

**How can I tell what device is triggering this activity?**

Answer (score 3):

> Now, whenever a device is trying to talk to my Mac (or vice versa, I suppose) I will see the Bluetooth icon with 3-dots through it.

**That's not what it means.**

The icon means that Bluetooth is enabled and at least one device is connected.

From the Apple Support Document, [Using a Bluetooth mouse, keyboard or trackpad with your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201171):

[image]

If you want to see what device is connected, just open the Bluetooth drop down menu.  Whatever is in **bold** is what's connected.

[image: Bluetooth Connections]

Comment: What about unpaired devices trying to connect?  Will that trigger the same icon state? Will that device be shown in this list?

Comment: No.  That's per Apple in the link I provided.